# SBQQ__ProductCode__c not visible in Tested Field in Error Condition of product rule

Tags: cpq

I am trying to learn CPQ.

My scenario is: I need to add product B in the cart if product A is added.

I have created product rule, added action.

I need to verify if product A is added using `SBQQ__ProductCode__c`.

For this, I am adding Error condition in the product rule.

I have selected **Product Option** in **Tested Object** and trying to select `SBQQ__ProductCode__c` in **Tested Field** but only seeing **Unit Price**:

[image]

What I may be missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I have just solved this one, had the same issue as I am doing some self paced training as well today. There is another step required beyond adding the picklist value to the SBQQ__TestedField__c field.

This picklist has a controlling picklist, called SBQQ__TestedObject__c and you need to update the field dependencies on this controlling field to include the picklist value you want to see when the object is selected.

[image: See I've added Location___c to the 'Configuration Attributes' picklist value]

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the Error Condition object and add the values you need to that picklist. Here's a help article on how to edit picklist values for a field: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=updating_picklists.htm&type=5.